# MongoDB Data API Injection Attacks

Tags: mongodb, sql-injection

I'm currently connecting to MongoDB using the [Data API](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/api/data-api/) to insert user-generated content that is sent by clients. However, it just occurred me that I didn't thought about injection attacks that may occur in the process of inserting data in the database via the API.

I can't find anything related to this on the official documentation, so I'm wondering: does the Data API perform some kind of sanitization/validation which prevents injection attacks?

Searched in official documentation and Google: no clear answers

Answer (score 0):

https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/07-Input_Validation_Testing/05.6-Testing_for_NoSQL_Injection has examples of MongoDB query expressions that can contain injected payload.

Basically, if an attacker can use some query selectors such as `$expr` or `$where` in a Data API query, they can pass an arbitrary Javascript functions that can do lots of mischief. Even if you restrict their user-level access controls, they could at least run costly Javascript functions designed to overtax your MongoDB server and thus cause a denial of service.

Both SQL and NoSQL injection are cases of a broader category of vulnerability called [code injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Code_Injection). Any system that accepts string input and uses that input as code to be parsed and executed at runtime, there's an opportunity for code injection. This also applies to `eval` commands in languages like shell or PHP or others. Even some compiled languages like Java have a feature to parse and execute code at runtime, e.g. [ScriptEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html).